# In payara server domain , How should i configuring different java version

Tags: java, payara

I have 2 different domains running on server. For one domain i need to configure Java 7 and for another domain java 8.Is it possible to configure different version of java for domains in Payara 4 Server?

Answer (score 0):

Java configuration on domain wise is not feasible. But in payara level, we can configure it.